# JavaScript If statement not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code, which is working great in firefox and chrome, but not working in Internet Explorer...

```
$("#nav-tabs").on("click", "a", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).tab('show');
    $('li#test').each(function() {
        if($(this).attr('class') == "active")
        {
            //Active class is applied
            $(this).children().children().attr("src", "assets/img/button_home_selected3.png");
        }
        else
        {
            $(this).children().children().attr("src", "assets/img/button_home_plain.png");
        }
    });
});
```

Is there any problems with conditional statements with IE???

Here is the HTML

```
<ul id="nav-tabs" data-tabs="tabs">
   <li id="test" style="list-style: none;" class="active">
        <a href="#home" data-toggle="tabs" ><img src="assets/img/button_home_selected3.png" id="test2"  width="83" /><span>Home</span></a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

More over, the li tags are Addded dynamically...

Comment: What is the error on IE? Any error message? And why you are making a loop over `$('li#test')`? How many elements with the same id you have?

Comment: Why you put `e.preventDefault();` just add `return false;` at the end of click callback

Comment: @PankajPhartiyal: `return false` (in jQuery) does **two** things: `preventDefault` *and* `stopPropagation`. Maybe the OP doesn't want to stop propagation. Maybe they just prefer the clarity of the explicit function call. Maybe they want to make sure that the default is prevented regardless of what branches are taken in their code, and regardless of whether the code throws an exception (hence putting it right up front). Etc. etc. etc.

Comment: The IE Console is not showing any error at all...

Answer (score 5):

depending on the actual html but you should always use `hasClass` when detecting whether or not an element has a given class

so change the if to

```
if($(this).hasClass("active")
```

which will be true if the element has the class `active` and not only if the value of the `class` attribute is exactly the value "active"

E.g. if you have

```
<img class=" active image" />
```

then `hasClass("active")` will be true but your test will be false and even

```
<img class=" active " />
```

might be treated differently in different browsers because of the whitespace around active

**EDIT based on comment**

You should hardly ever rely on the position of elements alone. The only scenario where you should rely on position is when the position it self is the key. E.g. when zebra colouring a table

I suggest that you change your code to the following

```
$("#nav-tabs").on("click", "a", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).tab('show');
    $('li#test').each(function() {
        var self = $(this), 
        source = self.hasClass("active") ? 
                      "assets/img/button_home_selected3.png") :
                      "assets/img/button_home_plain.png";
        self.children().
            .find(img:first).attr("src", source);
    });
});
```

There's a few points to notice.

- When you use $(this) multiple times. Store it in a local variable instead of selecting it multiple times
- Use a more specific selector than relying only on the order the elements are found in
- Narrow the selection to only select the needed elements also when the HTML is changed. In your case adding another image as a grand child to li#test would result in the code changing the `src` for both images at the same time
- if you perform the same operation twice with different arguments instead use the if to select the input and only implement the functionality once since this makes it both easier to read the code and easier to maintain. If your case that would be select the source of the image based on whether or not the active class is present and then set the `src` accordingly

Comment: i have done that already but still not working in Internet Explorer...
My functionality is simple, the active class toggles between the li tags, and the img tag between the li tag changes with this script

Comment: @Hunain you will have to provide a SSCCE then (http://SSCCE.org) or at least more context E.g. the actual HTMl

Comment: I Got it, in the dynamically added script i had appeded the li item second then the img tag, which made it confused; as there was no src....